# Can I make "starter" with active dry yeast?

Tags: baking, bread, yeast, cultured-food

I'd like to extend my supply of yeast (It's hard to get right now). My wife does not enjoy the taste of sourdough, so I was wondering it it's possible to create a self-replenishing culture, starting with store-bought, active dry yeast we already have on hand?

Comment: Hey! I had the same question yesterday.
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/107887/baking-lots-of-bread-keeping-a-yeast-starter

Comment: If you have the Joy of Cooking, I suggest checking out the "sponge starter" section. It basically gives three options -- reduce the yeast needed by about 5/6; store active culture in fridge; freeze culture.

Comment: @adam.r I'll check that out! We do have a copy of 'Joy'.